# cookie not shows in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, setcookie

I set a cookie with Codeigniter and it is Ok because I can see it in browser settings, but it doesn't shows when I am coding.
**set cookie:**

```
$login_text = "$username is loged in!";
            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $cookie_value = $this->encrypt->encode($login_text, ENCRYPTION_KEY);

            $data_cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'userRemember',
                'value'  => strval($cookie_value),
                'expire' => '1209600'
            );
```

**read cookie:**

```
print_r($this->input->cookie());
```

what is the problem?and how can I solve it?

Comment: You've not actually created the cookie anywhere. You just make an array that has information about the cookie in but don't actually do anything with it.

Comment: Have you looked at set_cookie codeIgniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html#set_cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use setcookie()

```
Setcookie("name", "value", "expire time");
```

Replace the strings with your values
Edit:

```
 Setcookie($data_cookie['name'], $data_cookie['value'], $data_cookie['expire']);
```

To read the cookie

```
Echo $_COOKIE($data_cookie['name']);
```